# Finding value in matrix from tuple

Tags: python

I have this matrix:

```
matrix = np.array([[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
              [3,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,3],
              [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]])
```

and a list of lists filled with tuples like these:

```
[[(10, 6), (10, 5), (10, 7), (9, 6), (9, 5), (9, 7)], [(9, 7), (9, 6), (9, 8), (8, 7), (8, 6), (8, 8), (10, 7), (10, 6), (10, 8)], [(10, 7), (10, 6), (10, 8), (9, 7), (9, 6), (9, 8)], [(8, 8), (8, 7), (8, 9), (7, 8), (7, 7), (7, 9), (9, 8), (9, 7), (9, 9)], [(9, 8), (9, 7), (9, 9), (8, 8), (8, 7), (8, 9), (10, 8), (10, 7), (10, 9)], [(10, 8), (10, 7), (10, 9), (9, 8), (9, 7), (9, 9)], [(7, 9), (7, 8), (7, 10), (6, 9), (6, 8), (6, 10), (8, 9), (8, 8), (8, 10)], [(8, 9), (8, 8), (8, 10), (7, 9), (7, 8), (7, 10), (9, 9), (9, 8), (9, 10)], [(9, 9), (9, 8), (9, 10), (8, 9), (8, 8), (8, 10), (10, 9), (10, 8), (10, 10)], [(10, 9), (10, 8), (10, 10), (9, 9), (9, 8), (9, 10)], [(6, 10), (6, 9), (5, 10), (5, 9), (7, 10), (7, 9)], [(7, 10), (7, 9), (6, 10), (6, 9), (8, 10), (8, 9)], [(8, 10), (8, 9), (7, 10), (7, 9), (9, 10), (9, 9)], [(9, 10), (9, 9), (8, 10), (8, 9), (10, 10), (10, 9)], [(10, 10), (10, 9), (9, 10), (9, 9)]]
```

which are the number i'm looking for and its neighboring spaces that aren't <10 in y or x, and I'm using a function to classify them between spaces filled with 0s or anything else and append them to a list. How do I correct this function which does the classification?

```
def classify(neighbors,matrix):
    for x in neighbors:
        y = x[0]
        z = x[1]
        if matrix[y][z] == 0:
            step.append(x)
        else:
            hop.append(x)

print(hop,step)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're looking for (especially the line `which are the number I'm looking for and its neighboring spaces...`). What is the expected output?

Comment: The tuple list is a space and it's neighboring spaces, I want to classify if the neighboring spaces IN THE MATRIX are occupied with a 0 or a different value and append the tuple to a list according to it's classification

Comment: What are you currently getting as a result, and what result, exactly, are you expecting?

Comment: I'm getting two empty lists and I expect to get for example: (10,5) is occupied with a 1 so (10,5) should be appended to the hop list and so on for all items on the list

Comment: Copying and pasting your code, I get: 
`>>> hop`
`[(10, 6), (10, 7), (9, 7)]`
`>>> step`
`[(10, 5), (9, 6), (9, 5)]`

Comment: check out the changes i made, i managed to make the parameter that gets sent as a list of lists of tuples

Comment: Just add another for loop...?

Comment: hadn't thought of that, thanks. No but for real, it won't let me iterate through the list item within the greater list.

Comment: Explain "won't let me".

Comment: it's taking the whole list of tuples as the thing I'm trying to classify, meaning it's not iterating through the tuples

Comment: `for a in list_of_lists:
  for b in list_of_tuples:
    y = b[0]
    z = b[1]`

Comment: but how do i enter to list of tuples? That's the real problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112926/discussion-between-rodrigo-cano-and-bozdoz).

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from array import *
matrix = np.array([[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
              [3,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3],
              [3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,3],
              [3,11,11,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,3],
              [3,12,12,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,3],
              [3,3,13,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]])

neighbors = [[(10, 6), (10, 5), (10, 7), (9, 6), (9, 5), (9, 7)],(10, 5),[(9, 7), (9, 6), (9, 8), (8, 7), (8, 6), (8, 8), (10, 7), (10, 6), (10, 8)]]
def classify(neighbors,matrix):
    hop = []
    step = []
    for x in neighbors:
      print x
      if isinstance(x,list):
        for x1 in x:
          y = x1[0]
          z = x1[1]
          if matrix[y][z] == 0:
             step.append(x1)
          else:
            hop.append(x1)
      else:
        y = x[0]
        z = x[1]
        if matrix[y][z] == 0:
             step.append(x)
        else:
            hop.append(x)

    print "neighbors which are not having value as zero =" ,hop
    print "neighbors which are having zero value =" ,step
classify(neighbors,matrix)
```

OUTPUT :-

```
neighbors which are not having value as zero = [(10, 6), (10, 7), (9, 7), (9, 7), (9, 8), (8, 8), (10, 7), (10, 6), (10, 8)]
neighbors which are having zero value = [(10, 5), (9, 6), (9, 5), (10, 5), (9, 6), (8, 7), (8, 6)]
```